# Accessibility Service : Setting cursor of webview EditText field

Tags: java, android, accessibilityservice, accessibility

I'm developing an Accessibility Service for Android. When I set text of EditText in webview it sets the text but places the cursor at the start.

```java
Bundle arguments = new Bundle();          
arguments.putCharSequence(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_SET_TEXT_CHARSEQUENCE, "String");
boolean actionResult = selectedNode.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_TEXT, arguments);
```

According to the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo#ACTION_SET_TEXT) it should put the cursor at the end of the text.

Also tried setting the cursor position using the following but this also didn't work in webview EditText

```java
Bundle argumentsSetCursor = new Bundle();
argumentsSetCursor.putInt(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_SELECTION_START_INT, finalCursorPosition);           
argumentsSetCursor.putInt(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_SELECTION_END_INT, finalCursorPosition);
selectedNode.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_SELECTION, argumentsSetCursor);
```

Note: Both of the above action works as expected in Android Native EditText, only fails in case of Webview EditText